# Using Top to show output of your Script

Tags: linux, top-command

In my previous company, there was an engineer who showed me a demo of using top and it was displaying the output of her script. Unfortunately, I do not have any contacts with her anymore. But I find it really amazing that top can display the output. It is like doing a tail -f on a log file.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: please clarify what you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top has a -b mode which prints out information in a format that looks like tail -f.  is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Cool, never seen `-b` before :)

Comment: Sometimes i need to log the output of top